# Baby Rudin 2.40: can an infinitely small subcover $G_\alpha$ be backward-constructed?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

My question is about exactly how small can a nbhd of $x^\ast$ be, or put in another way: is it possible that some subcover $G_\alpha$ be constructed along the way so that it each time (albeit narrowly) "escapes"? Rudin says "Since $G_{\alpha}$ is open , there exist $r >0$ such that $|y-x^\ast|<r $ implies  that $y \in G_{\alpha}$", fair enough, but why assume then that such an $r$ is fixed so that some very large $n$ can in some way exceed it? After all some $r^\prime \in (0,2^{-n}\delta)$  can always be found s.t.  $ Nr(x^\ast) \subset G_\alpha$ iff $r \leq r^\prime$, provided that we are not required to describe $G_\alpha$ beforehand.

> **Theorem 2.40** : Every k-cell is compact.
>
> **Proof**: Let $I$ be a $k$-cell consisting of points $\bf x$ with $a_j\le x_j\le
> > b_j$. Put
>
> $$ \delta =\left (\sum_1^k(b_j-a_j)^2\right )^{1/2}$$
>
> Then $|x-y|\le \delta, \forall x,y \in I$.
>
> Suppose, to get a contradiction, that there exists an open cover
> $\{G_{\alpha}\}$ which has no finite subcover of $I$.
>
> Put $c_{j}=(a_{j}+b_{j})/2$.  The intervals $[a_{j},c_{j}]$ and
> $[c_{j},b_{j}]$ then determine $2^{k}$ $k$-cells $Q_{i}$ whose union
> is $I$.
>
> One of these $Q_i$, call it $I_1$, will also have no finite subcover.
> Continuing this process we obtain a sequence $I_n$ with the following
> properties:
>
> 1. $I \supset I_1 \supset I_2 \supset I_3 \supset I_4 \supset \dots$.
> 2. $I_n$ is not covered by any finite subcollection of $\{ G_{\alpha}\}$.
> 3. If $x,y \in I_n$, the $|x-y| \leq 2^{-n}\delta$
>
> by $( a)$ and theorem $2.39$ , there is  a point $x^\ast$ which lie in
> every $I_n$. For some  $\alpha , x^\ast \in G_\alpha.$ Since
> $G_{\alpha}$ is open , there exist $r >0$ such that $|y-x^\ast|<r $
> implies  that $y \in G_{\alpha}$. If $n$ is so large that $2^{-n} \delta < r$ (there is such  an $n$ ,
> for otherwise  $2^n \le  \delta/r$ for all positive integr $n$ , which is  absurd since $R$ is archimedean , then $(c)$ implies that  ${I_n \subset G_{\alpha}}$ , which contradicts $(b)$.

A similar argument is used in theorem 2.44 (Cantor set), in a more explicit form by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/408096/1195730) answer:

> **Theorem**: The Cantor set $P$ contains no segment $(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\alpha < \beta$.

> **Proof:** By definition, $E_n$ does not contain any segments of length greater than $3^{-n}$. For some $m > 0$, the segment $(\alpha,\beta)$  satisfies $\beta - \alpha > 3^{-m}$ and so $(\alpha,\beta) \not\subset E_m$ and therefore, $(\alpha,\beta) \not\subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n = P$. $_\Box$

Comment: What are you talking about? Given $x^*\in G_\alpha$, since $G_\alpha$ is open, there is $r>0$ so that $B(x^*,r)\subset G_\alpha$.  You’re switching quantifiers all around, apparently.